# How to have a conditional statement within a control tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, hyperlink, repeater

I have a `Hyperlink` within a `Repeater`. What I'm wanting is to set the `NavigateUrl` to the page Url and add the query string to the end. I came up with:

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="myLink" runat="server" Text="My Link" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# Request.Url + "?Id= + Eval("Id") %>' />
```

This works fine. The problem is I want to some how add some logic so if the `Request.Url` already contains a query string then not add the id query string part.

How can I do this within the html page? Bear in mind I can't use *javascript* for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="myLink" runat="server" Text="My Link" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# Request.RawUrl.Contains("?") ? Request.RawUrl : 
    Request.RawUrl + "?Id= + Eval("Id") %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for two things to be able to build your navigation url correctly:

1. Does the url contain an *Id* parameter ??
2. Does the url already contain any parameter ??

Use the following:

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="myLink" runat="server" Text="My Link"     
    NavigateUrl='<%# Request.QueryString["Id"] == null ? 
    (Request.Url.Contains("?") ? Request.Url + "&Id= + Eval("Id") : 
    Request.Url + "?Id= + Eval("Id")) : Request.Url  %>' />
```

Comment: Question was: "Request.Url already contains a query string...". So no need to specifically check for the ID querystring

Comment: @Magnus: If you checked my expression you would discover it is not the same point ..

Comment: Im just saying `Request.QueryString["Id"] == null` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Magnus: The OP have not provided enough details to make that decision possible !!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<asp:Hyperlink ID="myLink" runat="server" Text="My Link" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# (Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("?") > -1 ? Request.Url.ToString() : Request.Url.ToString() + "?Id= + Eval("Id")) %>' />
```

You might also want to create a protected method on your code behind or if you would need this on multiple places create an Extension Method.

```
protected string AddIdToRequestUrl(object id)
{
  return Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("?") > -1 ? 
    Request.Url.ToString() :
    Request.Url.ToString() + "?Id=" + id.ToString();
}

<asp:Hyperlink ID="myLink" runat="server" Text="My Link" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# AddIdToRequestUrl(Eval("Id")) %>' />
```

Comment: You have to modify the function to match the expression !!